# Why, on Linux (specifically Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), a POSIX shared memory object survives reboot and then suddenly belongs to the "root" user?

Tags: c, linux, posix, shared-memory

### Important notice

The problem is **not** resolved at all and it was **not** caused by a typo. Just because some person said that they cannot reproduce it (and they may be right, as far as their local test setup is concerned), it does **not** mean the problem doesn't exist for me. I can perfectly reproduce the problem and I'm still looking for a solution or explanation.

If any more information is needed, please tell me **what** is needed.

#### Demonstration

[Here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/6gy3muuv5unq7zd/2024-03-10_18-24-20.mp4/file) is a short video clip that demonstrates the problem.

---

### Original Question

I'm using a POSIX shared memory to share some common state between multiple instances of my application. The POSIX shared memory is created via the `shm_open()` function, it is expanded to the required size via `ftruncate()` and it is then mapped into the memory via `mmap()` function. I also create a Semaphore, via the `sem_open()` function, which is used to synchronize the access to the shared memory and to make sure that the *first* instance performs the initialization.

So far, this seems to be working fine. And I also see that my shared memory objects appear under `/dev/shm/` with the proper owner and permissions, all as expected. But, on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) I'm seeing some ***really strange*** behavior: After a reboot, the shared memory object (and the semaphore too!) is still there. How is that even possible? After all, to the best of my knowledge, shared memory objects are *volatile*, i.e. the `/dev/shm/` filesystem is a ***tmpfs*** that lives entirely in RAM and therefore can **not** survive a reboot. Even worse, after the reboot, the *owner* of my shared memory object has changed from the original user to "root" for **no** apparent reason! This means that if I launch my application again, *after a reboot*, then the `shm_open()` *fails* with permission denied! So, there must be "something" that persists the shared memory to disk when the system is going down, and that restores them when the system is booting up again. But why the mysterious owner change that makes the "persisted" shared memory *inaccessible*?

Note: I have checked this on MacOS X and FreeBSD, but neither seems to have this behavior.

I tested, *multiple times*, that, on Linux, `ls -al /dev/shm` shows the original owner for my shared memory (and semaphore) just before the reboot, and that it shows "root" as the owner just after the reboot. The application did **not** run in between the two `ls -al /dev/shm` invocations. Only way to get things working again is to `sudo rm -f /dev/shm/*` after each reboot. But that cannot be the "solution", right? What is the "standard" way to deal with this issue on Linux ???

---

My code looks like this:

```
static unsigned char *initialize(const int create_shmem)
{
    void *buffer = NULL;

    int fd = shm_open(OBJECT_NAME, create_shmem ? O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR : O_RDONLY, 0644);
    if (fd < 0) {
        if ((!create_shmem) && (errno == ENOENT)) {
            return initialize(1);
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    if (create_shmem) {
        if (ftruncate(fd, BUFFER_SIZE) != 0) {
            goto failure;
        }
    }

    buffer = mmap(NULL, BUFFER_SIZE, create_shmem ? PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE : PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0U);
    if (buffer == MAP_FAILED) {
        goto failure;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

---

I know that I could *explicitly* remove the shared memory, via `shm_unlink()` function, prior to the reboot, which would probably avoid the problem. But this is really **not** reliable! If once the application misses a proper clean-up for whatever reason (e.g. crash) and then the system is rebooted, we end up with a shared memory object that can **no** longer be accessed.

---

Interestingly, I found that **systemd login manager** has a configuration option **`RemoveIPC`** which *"Controls whether System V and POSIX IPC objects belonging to the user shall be removed when the user fully logs out"*. However, this does **not** seem to effect shared memory objects belonging to the "root" user (*"Note that IPC objects of the root user and other system users are excluded from the effect of this setting"*). Also this does **not** explain why, on reboot, the ownership of existing shared memory objects is transferred from the previous owner to the "root" user, instead of just deleting the shared memory. Deletion would be okay, because then we would be able to just re-create it, as the normal user. There seems to be **no** similar option to have "root"-owned objects deleted too.

[Source](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/logind.conf.5.html)

---

Does Linux offer a sort of "boot counter", which is incremented every time that the system is powered on or rebooted? If so, then I could just append *that* counter to the name of my object in order to work around the problem of "old" objects (names) being blocked by the "root" user.

---

I have now created a systemd service unit that runs when the system is shutting down and that calls a script which ***deletes*** everything from `/dev/shm` directory. From my log I can see (later) that my "delete" script actually ran when the system was shutting down. And I can see that it actually deleted the existing shared memory from the `/dev/shm` directory. Nonetheless, when I inspect `/dev/shm` after the reboot, the shared memory is back and is now owned by "root" user!!

I can only assume that this is happening because "whatever" is saving the contents of `/dev/shm` to disk when the system is rebooting does this *before* my delete script gets a chance to run...

Comment: Is there any chance the program is automatically started on boot as root? Maybe it's in /etc/rc.d or systemd?

Comment: Nope, certainly not. I tested, *multiple times*, that `ls -al /dev/shm` shows the original owner just before the reboot and it shows "root" as the owner just after the reboot. The application did **not** run at all in between the two `ls -al /dev/shm` invocations.

Comment: While probably not off topic here, this might be worth asking on the unix & linux stack exchange.

Comment: Shouldn't be happening.  Maybe /dev/shm isn't really tmpfs like it should be, or there is another fs also mounted on top the tmpfs one?  Or perhaps there is some shutdown script that is saving the contents of /dev and restoring it, and this script doesn't understand that the files in /dev/shm are not device nodes and it shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Test system is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, installed from the ISO image and pretty much *unmodified* from the default installation, except that I `apt install`ed the required development tools. So, whatever is going on, appears to be the "default" behavior of Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS running on AWS.

Comment: @kichik Neither was I on any system other than Linux 20.04 LTS. So I'm beginning to believe this might be some "quirk" of that specific Linux distro. Maybe AWS has a different default configuration? Nonetheless, it is safe to assume that many people out there use Linux 20.04 LTS with its "default" configuration. So I need a solution that works in this scenario...

Comment: If I were you, I would try to recreate your VM/machine using the same Linux version and run a minimal example of the code there. Use specifically the code from the question with nothing else.

Comment: @kichik I understand your suggestion to use a minimal example code. However, in order to reproduce the "problem" my program (or any program) does **not** need to run at all. I see that the shared memory exists in `/dev/shm` with the owner that has created the shared memory. Then I immediately reboot the VM and, *without doing anything else*, I see that the owner of the shared memory in `/dev/shm` has now been changed to "root" user! Maybe I will re-create the VM, just to be sure...

Comment: I have no intention of trying to reproduce this (don't want to reboot), but on my 20.04 box the only thing using /dev/shm is postgres, and it's owned by postgres  :)

Comment: Ok, here's a simpler one. Manually create a whole other file in /dev/shm, reboot, and see if it's there.

Comment: @kichik Yeah, I can manually create files in the `/dev/shm` directory, but they are completely gone after reboot. So, apparently, even though Linux shows the existing shared memory objects in `/dev/shm`, it does **not** mean that *manually* creating a file there actually creates a shared memory object. The shared memory object created by `shm_open()` syscall remains after reboot and its ownership is transferred to "root". Manually created files in `/dev/shm` do **not** survive reboot.

Comment: Ok. Then try running the minimal sample code above as a separate program with a separate shm name. If that one still stays, it will be more reasonable to assume something is persisting shm with wrong permissions.

Comment: System administration is categorically off-topic here. Stack Overflow is **only** for questions about _writing code_.

Comment: And `/dev/shm` isn't special in a way that means everything there is a POSIX shared memory object; it's just tmpfs -- it's a conventional place for programs to put files they intend to `mmap()` in such a way that other processes can `mmap()` the same file to share the same memory. POSIX SHM is a completely different thing (and absolutely none of its documentation is relevant at all), so the present title is utterly misleading.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Okay, then please contribute something useful to this topic and tell me how to write code that creates a POSIX shared memory object on the Linux operating system (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) *as a "normal" (non "root") user* in away that this POSIX shared memory object will still be accessible *as a "normal" (non "root") user* after the next reboot. It would also be okay if the POSIX shared memory would simply be gone (and could be re-created) after the reboot. All example code for `shm_open()` that I have found does **not** deal with this issue...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `/dev/shm` may *not* be "special" in the sense that we can create files there as in any other directory. However, it *is* "special" in the sense that POSIX shared memory objects created via the `shm_open()` system function appear in `/dev/shm` and – much unlike regular files that we manually create in `/dev/shm` – *those* files that represent POSIX shared memory objects (created via `shm_open()`) persist after a reboot, and will be owned by "root" after the reboot. I don't know "what" persists/restores POSIX shared memory objects on reboots, but I suspect *systemd* is involved.

Comment: There's no such thing. SHM is nonpersistant by nature; if you want something to set up a new segment on reboot, that calls for creating something like a systemd service to run on next boot. As for the claim made in the question that something is recreating `/dev/shm` content on reboot... I'll believe it when I see it with my own eyes, and not before. (BTW, one thing I've done when debugging bizarre things happening early at boot time in the past is setting up a service to run sysdig dumped to tmpfs to track all userland syscalls; alas, this was proprietary to a former employer)

Comment: BTW, while Linux doesn't have a boot _counter_, it does have a boot _UUID_; that's available from `/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It would be great if it was that way! The "problem" is that, at least in Linux (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS default installation) not only *do* POSIX shared memory objects survive the reboot, the owner changes to "root" after the reboot so that I'm no longer able to access the "old" shared memory objects after the reboot. I don't observe this behavior on either MacOS X or FreeBSD. If I knew how to prevent Linux from persisting the shared memory objects it would be fine! Systemd *has* some options to control when shared memory objects are deleted, but it doesn't effect "root"-owned objects.

Comment: @Schraubstock1990 - as I said: not on my 20.04. Can't reproduce. Not on 18.04 at work, either, nor on Debian Bookworm. I can't say how you managed to get this behaviour, but it's not only off-topic, it's localised.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just installed Linux (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) from the official ISO image and did *not* configure anything special. Still, this is what I am seeing: https://www.mediafire.com/file/6gy3muuv5unq7zd/2024-03-10_18-24-20.mp4/file I fear that other users may see the same issue when using my app.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It seems that `/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id` returns a *different* value very time I read it. It does *not* stay fixed for the session. So, unfortunately, this can not be used to agree on a POSIX shared memory name between multiple instances, as each instance would end up with a *different* name. I'd need something that stays ***fixed*** for a session, but changes on each reboot (power up).

Comment: @Schraubstock1990 returns the same value on consecutive reads here (Ubuntu 24.04, Linux 6.8.0)

Comment: @knittl Ah, my bad. I used `/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid` instead of `/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id`. The latter indeed works as intended! So, yeah, I could use the "boot_id" to generate a unique name for my POSIX shared memory object that remains constant until reboot and that changes on every reboot. Still, the "old" objects will pile up in `\dev\shm`, which isn't exactly nice. You probably should post this as an answer, so I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: longshot: maybe it's some virtualbox option, of the "fast reboot" kind? I'd try on a VB on another machine.  Also, I'd try more permissions for debugging.

Comment: @Agent_L I don't think there is any option in VirtualBox that might be related. Also I'm **not** aware of a "fast reboot" option in Linux. If such option exists, I haven't tuned it on (intentionally).

Comment: Since you are using a VM, it may happens that /dev/shm of the hosted machine is backed up in some way on the host machine.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Well, of course the contents of the virtual HDD are stored in an image file on the host machine. But there must be something happening *inside* of the VM that persists `/dev/shm` to the (virtual) HDD when the system is shutting down and that restores it from there (with the wrong owner!) after the reboot. I still don't know **what** is doing this, but I suspect *systemd*, as systemd apparently is responsible for deleting entries from `/dev/shm` (it has options for that). I don't think any of this is "VM specific". And **no**, I don't use "shared folders" with VirtualBox.

Comment: @Schraubstock1990 on the contrary I suspect something weird with the Vm hosting system. I doubt this can be replicated on bare metal (of course I may be wrong). What I read about this was always related to VMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78128006/why-on-linux-specifically-ubuntu-20-04-lts-a-posix-shared-memory-object-surv/78146049#comment137751760_78128006), on Linux, we can use `/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id` to get a unique ID that changes on every reboot, but that remains fixed as long as the system is running. This is a great way to generate a unique name for my POSIX shared memory, such that different processes can agree on the *same* name, but still that name changes after a reboot. Hence we can avoid name conflicts with "old" shared memories that are no longer accessible.

Comment: May be related: https://www.reddit.com/r/unRAID/comments/1116xno/permissions_for_devshm_are_undone_after_reboot/

Comment: Also related https://superuser.com/questions/1117764/why-are-the-contents-of-dev-shm-is-being-removed-automatically